# How do I detect the existence of a particular page in a URL?

Tags: php, regex, url, curl

I am trying to check whether a particular URL is present in a page supplied by another website.

I need to check whether or not the given URL contains a link to my website.

I am using PHP, and I would like to use preg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the url you are looking for, can't you use  `strpos()`?

```
if (strpos($your_html_page, 'your_url') !== false) {
    echo 'The web web page has your_url in it.';
}
```

This is a simple match - but it doesn't tell you whether it's a hyperlink - just if the url is somwehere in the page. If you want to verify is actually a hyperlink than this approach **or a simple regex** is not going to help (at least a regex is likely to be fiddly and unreliable). You need to [parse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) the DOM properly, extract out the `<a>` elements and check against the href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

And for the parsing part you could use the [simple html dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
html = file_get_html('http://stackoverflow.com/');

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
   if( preg_match($your_website_url, $element->href) > 0){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: I want a to use simple regex script to get my match

Comment: @KoolKabin : Using `preg_match` is using regex.

Comment: @KoolKabin : you wanted links to your website, simple html parser filters a tags, something you should try to avoid doing with regex

Answer (score 0):

Well, you fetch the content using [streams](http://phpadvent.org/2010/streams-by-lisa-denlinger) and then you parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i had to do that...

here is the regular expresion

`preg_match_all( '/<a[^>]*href=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $message, $links );`

in th array `$links` you will have 2 arrays.

0 - The complete `<a>` tags

1 - The Url of the href attributes